# How to download Yosemite Beta from the Beta Program?

Tags: mac-appstore, macos, beta-seed-program

I signed up on the OS X Beta Program site to test Yosemite. Was given a redemption code and automatically directed to App Store. Redemption code was already filled into the manual input box in App Store but there was no option to download. Tried again, and App Store said redemption code already used. Can anyone suggest how I get the download?

Comment: Have you logged into the beta seed program and read the FAQ? I would expect Apple to explain how to operate the installation and or trouble shoot the app store. I don't have access to that program, so perhaps someone else has experience they are willing to share despite the NDA.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Purchases in the Mac App Store. There you should see it.